# Insert Min Log Time and Max Log Time by Emp_ID and Credit Date in Database

Tags: mysql, vb.net, max, reportviewer, min

I want to save in my databse the min value of log time where log type is equal to I and max value of log time where log type is equal to O .. need to save by date and by Emp_ID in my datatabase. I dont know how to start the data below is import to reportviewer. The min and max value below is expression in reportviewer.

```
  query = "  SELECT Emp_ID, MIN(Log_Time) AS timein, MAX(Log_Time) AS timeout, Credit_date FROM(tbl_timelogs) GROUP BY Emp_ID, Credit_date"
```

[image]

[image]

The data must in the database like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query works need to declare value of min and max.

```
query = "  SELECT Emp_ID, MIN(Log_Time) AS timein, MAX(Log_Time) AS timeout, Credit_date        FROM(tbl_timelogs) GROUP BY Emp_ID, Credit_date"
```